# How route get method with query params .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i call web api get method from desktop app.

this is call method

```
private static async Task<Interval> Check(Interval checkGet)
        {
            var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>(2);
            queryParams.Add("DateStart", intervalForGet.DateStart.ToString());
            queryParams.Add("DateEnd", intervalForGet.DateEnd.ToString());

            string requestUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("http://localhost:58232/api/Check", queryParams);

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);

            var createdTask = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Interval>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());    
            return createdTask;
        }
```

model

```
public class Interval
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
        }
```

When i debug this code i see next requestUri
`http://localhost:58232/api/Check?DateStart=03.01.2018%200%3A00%3A00&DateEnd=03.01.2018%200%3A00%3A00`

this is get method from web api

```
[HttpGet("api/Check/{DateStart}/{DateEnd}")]
        public async Task<List<Intervals>> Check([FromQuery]string urlString)
        {
          //some code
        }
```

this is startup class

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

tell me. how to make a route, because my `[HttpGet("api/Check/{DateStart}/{DateEnd}")]` not work for me

Comment: i think the Check method must be ``[Route("api/Check")]
[HttpGet]
public void insertRecLoadData(DateTime DateStart, DateTime DateEnd)`` let me know if it's work fine, i can added it like an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your caller :

```
var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync($"http://localhost:58232/api/Check/{intervalForGet.DateStart.ToString()}/{intervalForGet.DateEnd.ToString()}");
```

In your api

```
[HttpGet("api/Check/{DateStart}/{DateEnd}")]
        public async Task<List<Intervals>> Check(DateTime DateStart,DateTime DateEnd)
        {
          //some code
        }
```

Don’t forget pass your date with correct format like 2020-11-12

Comment: ok. but how send this date to GetAsync(); which input uriI. I am added values (DateStart and DateEnd) to uri and then try route

Comment: @ SadeqHatami Fiddler say HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found. i send ```http://localhost:58232/api/Check/03.01.2018/03.01.2018``` and i see 404 error(. When i send with 0```2020-11-12/2020-11-12``` same error

Comment: @ SadeqHatami i find problem, error in url ```http://localhost:58232/api/Check/api/Check``` and then ```/03.01.2018/03.01.2018``` its url to method and url to web api method. but i want use only /api/Check/. maybi you know how to do this